# Don't destruct object when returned

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, gpu

I'm making a C++ cuda program, in which (as far as I know):

```
cudaMallocManaged(&data, size);
```

and

```
cudaFree(&data);
```

is analogous to `malloc/new` and `delete`.

Say I have a class

```
struct vec{

    int size;
    int* data;

    vec(int size){
        cudaMallocManaged(&data, x * y * sizeof(int));
    }

};
```

and I overload the + operator:

```
vec operator+(vec b){

        vec c;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            c.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
        }
        return c;

    }

mat<T> operator+(int b){

        vec c;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            c.data[i] = a.data[i] + b;
        }
        return c;

    }
```

now say I have some function:

```
vec f(vec x){
    return x + ​x + 1;
```

​}

Since this function creates 2 vectors, If this function is called repeatedly all the gpu memory is used up. The obvious solution is adding a deconstructor to the vec class which frees the memory when the object goes out of scope:

```
~vec(){
    cudaFree(data);
}
```

The problem that arises is that since a pointer is being deleted, and the returned vector stores its data in the same pointer, the returned data is also deleted and the program crashes with a 0xc0000006 error when the data is next referenced.

One thing I considered is something like this:

```
void add(vec a, vec b, vec out){

        vec c;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            c.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
        }
        copy(c to out); //I'm not 100% sure if memcpy works in cuda

}
```

However, that is not only inconvenient but also doesn't allow for operator overloading. Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: search for the rule of three.

Comment: What does this question have to do with the C language?

Comment: If your attempt to add your `~vec()` function led to a crash, you have a bug somewhere else - not described in this question.  If I were to guess, you omitted a copy constructor leading to multiple `vec`s sharing the same data pointer.  (Again, rule of 3)

Comment: Yes, I was previously unaware of the rule of 3 and a copy constructor. Thank you all for your help.